# How would I implement this Objective-C Line in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, pointers, reference, uikit

In a library called `UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll` (linked [here](https://github.com/pronebird/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll)) you can find *this* line of code in `Classes/UIScrollView+InfiniteScroll.m`:

`static const void *kPBInfiniteScrollStateKey = &kPBInfiniteScrollStateKey;`

How do I rewrite this line in Swift? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have helped *a lot* should have you included the original comment

```
// Keys for values in associated dictionary
static const void *kPBInfiniteScrollStateKey = &kPBInfiniteScrollStateKey;
```

You can use associated objects like this in Swift, courtesy of erhatsezer https://gist.github.com/serhatsezer/4abe382229b001b37b1ee2f46e62b90f#file-productdetail-extension-swift

```
private var associateKey: Void?

extension ProductDetail {
    var totalSumOfBasket: String? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &associateKey) as? String
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &associateKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a genius, thank you so much. I wouldn't've known how to do this myself. This is undocumented though, which is absolutely ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Most basic way to do that its using https://swiftify.com tool. Easiest way to convert objc to swift.

Also for infinite scrollView best solution I found is https://github.com/rebeloper/DScrollview it's completely written in swift.

Comment: I initially tried porting the project I mentioned into Swift using Swiftify and some other transpiler, but both solutions gave me syntax errors in Xcode, which is why I ended up asking the question. Thanks a lot for the Infinite Scroll View solution, though!